# Overwrite CodeIgniter Common.php

Tags: codeigniter

There is a method in **code igniter** under **system/core/Common.php** called **load_class**().

I would like to overwrite this method. Usually to overwrite a code igniter class I create a file such as **MY_Common.php** however in this case **Common.php** is a collection of methods and there are no classes that encapsulates them.

So how exactly do I do this?

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite that method?

Comment: because of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15833762/running-load-class-on-mthaml

Comment: well, you could just have that two lines of code for your haml include + autoloader registration inside a `MY_Controller::__constructor()` or in a hook and you won't have to fiddle with CI internals.

Comment: btw you see in the example the file starts with use do I need to have these? https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml/blob/master/examples/example.php

Comment: We are getting seriously offtopic here, but i would move the example code to `MY_Controller::__constructor` (without the `use`-es) up until line 10 making it like `$this->haml = new Environment('twig');` so in your controllers you can simply do `$this->haml->compileString(...)`; somethinh along the lines of [this](https://gist.github.com/complex857/5319040)

Comment: got it :) thanks alot complex857!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no officially supported way to do this by the built in extending mechanisms. Consider some other way to achieve your goal.

**However** the functions inside `Common.php` are all wrapped inside an `if` checking if the function is already exists or not so you can do the following:

1. Create your `MY_Common.php` put somewhere in your project (maybe `application/core/` to mirror other similar extends)
2. Open your `index.php` file in the root of the project
3. insert `include APPPATH.'core/MY_Common.php';` **before** the closing 
    `require_once BASEPATH.'core/CodeIgniter.php';` line

Now if you have you have a `load_class` function in your `MY_Common.php` it will shadow the original version.

Comment: I see, kind of hackish naturally since it's not supported but could work, thank you.

Comment: Ok,nice way, but how can a call the functions when i need to use both of them simultaneously ? In your solution we are losing the original function.

Comment: @kasra, The short answer is that you can't. PHP won't allow you to have both of them with the same name, and you want your version with the original name (this is the whole point). The easiest way seems to me that you just edit the original file and rename things, or maybe adding a namespace to the file. I'm afraid you are out of luck here with php, maybe if you have [runkit](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) you can make it work with [runkit_function_rename](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php)

Comment: @complex857, this hackish solution would work as codeigniter already uses a `if ( ! function_exists('***'))` wrapper for all defined functions in `Common.php`

Answer (score 0):

The correct/official way to do that is overwriting the core common function into ie. `common_helper.php` `application/helpers` and setting up in `config/autoload.php`

Comment: That doesn't work as Common.php is loaded before the helpers, resulting in `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare log_message()...`