# running load_class on mthaml

Tags: php, codeigniter, haml, mthaml

I'm trying to use load_class to load mthaml as I understood it's necessary for performance reasons.

**This is the MtHaml library.**
https://github.com/arnaud-lb/MtHaml

It's namespaced everywhere so getting it working with load_class natively hits the first hurdle.
Then it gets instantiated through Autoloader.php which does

```
namespace MtHaml;

class Autoloader
{
    static public function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array(new self, 'autoload'));
    }

    static public function autoload($class)
    {
        if (strncmp($class, 'MtHaml', 6) !== 0) {
            return;
        }

        if (file_exists($file = __DIR__ . '/../' . strtr($class, '\\', '/').'.php')) {
            require $file;
        }
    }
```

I'm trying

```
load_class('Autoloader', 'libraries/MtHaml', '');
```

But that gives me **Fatal error: Class 'Autoloader' not found**

Then if I try

```
load_class('MtHaml\Autoloader', 'libraries/MtHaml', '');
```

I get **Unable to locate the specified class: MtHaml\Autoloader.php**

Right now the only way I got this working is by calling it like so

```
    require_once __DIR__ . '/../libraries/MtHaml/Autoloader.php';
    MtHaml\Autoloader::register();
    $haml = new MtHaml\Environment('php');
    $rendered = $haml->compileFile($haml_file, $haml_cache_path);
```

The problem being this piece of code is ran anytime I call my $this->load->view in code igniter so I understood load_class was needed to optimize performance as in one controller I could be calling $this->load->view several times.

How do I use load_class with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to use load_class to load mthaml as I understood it's necessary for performance reasons.

As far as I've unterstood mt-haml this is not necessary at all. `load_class` is from codeigniter, instead just install the mt-haml package and include it's autoloader and you should be fine already.